# how to automatically find and replace in java

Tags: java, regex, replace, find

i have stuck at a point in my java application.
the scenario is that i have string in the database like below

```
jogging(?x)
```

and a user enter via textbox something like

```
jogging(peter)
```

which mean that ?x refers to peter and has to replace it.
what i searched and learned is that i have to use regex to find similarity of jogging(___) so the blank can be ?x or alan. then i have to find if there is a question mark in the start to it has to be found and if there is not question mark it has to be replaces via string.replaceall function.

please let me know if i am at right direction and if not what other method can i go for.

Comment: you only want to replace the `?x` with an other string? sorry your question is not clear to me. Is there a change to have something else that needs to be replaced?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want to retrieve all the names which have a pattern `jogging(<name>)`? What does 'replaceAll' has to do with it?

Comment: @Shahensha Khan, you could use simple find("jogging("), get the index. Use the index+length("jogging(") as the start index and ")" as the end index. Replace the substring with whatever you wanted.

Comment: Replace all because i can have repetitions of jogging(?x). But once its found then i can replace all instances. Its one part i can have more statement like that e.g jogging(?x) running(?y) and user can input jogging(peter), running(alan).

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan sorry friend, your comment doesnt help at all. Explain (with examples) what you want to do. you have a DB, you query and get some results. in these results there are some records that have strings as `jogging(?x)` and need to replace the `?x` with some other string?

Comment: The thing is that the input has to match with the pattern of stored string. E.g input is swimming(duck) And stored in strings i have swimmimg(?z) so it has to update the swimming (?z) with swimming(duck)

Comment: @Skaros ilias yes as u said.it will help me as well.

Comment: If you see that everything before the first '(' is the same can't you just replace the entire inputted string with the entire string in the DB?

Comment: Why not doing the regex matching on the database? It could be quite expensive to load all records and then do the matching in memory. I'd recommend you to try to do it on the database and, if not possible, then do it in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys i have done it, maybe not the best way but simplest way.

```
String in_db;//assume it swimming(?x)
String user="swimming(duck)"; 

//next splitting it at the ( which will seperate the before and after ( in the string and save into array carrying first part in array[0] and rest in the array[1].
String in_dp_parts[]=in_db.split("\\(");
String user_parts[]=user.split("\\(");
// next match if the first parts of the two arrays are same then assign the rest of the first array to second one.
if(user_parts[0].equals(in_db_parts(0)))
{
  in_db[1]=user[1];//assign the user provided value to in_db ?x
}
```

worked for me the code above is an example. tweak as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try string

```
replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement);
```

method with enter key event perform

Comment: The target and replacement are not known.it has to be done automatically

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question for sure, but this might do the trick
first you need to check if there is a `?` in your string,

```
String fromDB="swimming(?x)";
if(fromDB.indexof('?')>0){
    //a ? is found
    String userInput="swimming(name);
    //check if "verb" is the same eg swimming
    if(fromDB.substring(0,"(").equals(userInput.substring(0,"(")){
            //both strings are equal before the (
            //if fromDB string has ?x in it, will be replaces by the substring of userInfo that is between the ()
            fromDB.replace("?x",userInput.substring(a.indexOf("("),a.indexOf(")")-1);
     }
}
```

Disclaimer, did not test it, but should work.

Comment: that sounds working, ill b back to it once i try it.

Comment: at the following line
if(fromDB.substring(0,"(").equals(userInput.substring(0,"(")){
it wants an integer instead of "(" , i also tried using indexof("(") to get the index of ( but it says String can not be converted to int. i also tried assigning the indexof("(") to int x but same error

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan change `"` to `'` it needs a char not string.

Comment: really thanks for ur time, it really helped. any how i found a solution and its working now.

Comment: if you found  a solution you should post it here and accept it as correct. By the way Estebans comment is more to the point. try to narrow your database results using the users input

Comment: i already pasted as an answer :) the problem is that i m working on the rule based expert system and the rules are entered by the user and it has to remain intact only the clone of the rulebase is used as a reference for execution.

Comment: let me know ur view on the answer i have added @Skaros

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
String str = "jogging(?x)";
String str2 = str.replaceAll("(\\??x)", "peater");
```

out put will be:-

```
jogging(peater)
```

Comment: but i need to find before replacing them. if jogging(?x) and inoput is jogging(alan) then ?x = alan